# Users credentials saved at the SQL DBMS level

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, authentication

I'm filling in for my boss while he's away and the auditors came by to ask some questions about our SQL 2005 & 2008 environment. I'm not exactly an SQL expert and user access management at the database level all sounds very confusing to me. Based on some preliminary research I've done so far, I think I've narrowed down user access management at the SQL DBMS level to these two factors:

1. If a user is created within an application that is supported by an SQL database, the user will automatically be assigned to the public server role (provided that it is not manually assigned to another role).

   If the public server role is not granted the CONNECT privilege, am I right to assume that all of the application users created this way will be unable to log into the SQL database?
2. Even if the public server role is granted the CONNECT privilege, as long as the UserName(s) granted the public role have a NULL LoginName, am I right that they will still be unable to connect directly to the database?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL server 2005? Did they ask why you're using an unsupported DBMS?

Comment: Honestly couldn't tell you. I typically just work our service desk platform. They didn't seem to care in previous years so I guess it's not a problem?